# "A case label may only be used within a switch"

Tags: c++, menu, switch-statement, label, case

I am new to coding, and need some help with something. I am sorting out cases from a GTA Mod Menu, and trying to add a new one from an SDK. When I try to add it, and add a case for it so it knows what to do, I get the error in the title. I am coding in C++.

```
    int activeLineIndexVeh = 0;

void process_veh_menu()
{
    const float lineWidth = 230.0;
    const int lineCount = 9;

    std::string caption = "Vehicle Options";

    static struct {
        LPCSTR      text;
        bool        *pState;
        bool        *pUpdated;
    } lines[lineCount] = {
        { "Car Spawner", NULL, NULL },
        { "Random Paint", NULL, NULL },
        { "Fix", NULL, NULL },
        { "Custom Plate", NULL, NULL },
        { "Seat Belt", &featureVehSeatbelt, &featureVehSeatbeltUpdated },
        { "Wrap In Spawned", &featureVehWrapInSpawned, NULL },
        { "Invincible", &featureVehInvincible, &featureVehInvincibleUpdated },
        { "Strong Wheels", &featureVehInvincibleWheels, &featureVehInvincibleWheelsUpdated },
        { "Speed Boost", &featureVehSpeedBoost, NULL }
    };

    DWORD waitTime = 150;
    while (true)
    {
        // timed menu draw, used for pause after active line switch
        DWORD maxTickCount = GetTickCount() + waitTime;
        do
        {
            // draw menu
            draw_menu_line(caption, lineWidth, 7.9, 14.0, 4.0, 4.0, false, true);
            for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
                if (i != activeLineIndexVeh)
                    draw_menu_line(line_as_str(lines[i].text, lines[i].pState),
                    lineWidth, 4.0, 60.0 + i * 22.8, 4.0, 9.0, false, false);
            draw_menu_line(line_as_str(lines[activeLineIndexVeh].text, lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState),
                lineWidth + 0.0, 2.0, 60.0 + activeLineIndexVeh * 22.9, 4.0, 7.0, true, false);

            update_features();
            WAIT(0);
        } while (GetTickCount() < maxTickCount);
        waitTime = 0;

        // process buttons
        bool bSelect, bBack, bUp, bDown;
        get_button_state(&bSelect, &bBack, &bUp, &bDown, NULL, NULL);
        if (bSelect)
        {
            menu_beep();

            // common variables
            BOOL bPlayerExists = ENTITY::DOES_ENTITY_EXIST(PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID());
            Player player = PLAYER::PLAYER_ID();
            Ped playerPed = PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID();

            switch (activeLineIndexVeh)
            {
            case 0:
                if (process_carspawn_menu()) return;
                break;
            case 1:
                if (bPlayerExists)
                {
                    if (PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed, 0))
                    {
                        Vehicle veh = PED::GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_USING(playerPed);
                        VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_CUSTOM_PRIMARY_COLOUR(veh, rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255);
                        if (VEHICLE::GET_IS_VEHICLE_PRIMARY_COLOUR_CUSTOM(veh))
                            VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_CUSTOM_SECONDARY_COLOUR(veh, rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        set_status_text("player isn't in a vehicle");
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (bPlayerExists)
                    if (PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed, 0))
                        VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_FIXED(PED::GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_USING(playerPed));
                    else
                        set_status_text("player isn't in a vehicle");
                break;
                // switchable features
            default:
                if (lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState)
                    *lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState = !(*lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState);
                if (lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pUpdated)
                    *lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pUpdated = true;
            }
            waitTime = 200;
        }
        else
            if (bBack || trainer_switch_pressed())
            {
                menu_beep();
                break;
            }
            else
                if (bUp)
                {
                    menu_beep();
                    if (activeLineIndexVeh == 0)
                        activeLineIndexVeh = lineCount;
                    activeLineIndexVeh--;
                    waitTime = 150;
                }
                else
                    if (bDown)
                    {
                        menu_beep();
                        activeLineIndexVeh++;
                        if (activeLineIndexVeh == lineCount)
                            activeLineIndexVeh = 0;
                        waitTime = 150;
                    }
        case 3: // error starts here
            Ped playerPed = PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID();

            // No point in displaying the keyboard if they aren't in a vehicle
            if (!PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed, false)) return;

            // Invoke keyboard
            GAMEPLAY::DISPLAY_ONSCREEN_KEYBOARD(true, "", "", VEHICLE::GET_VEHICLE_NUMBER_PLATE_TEXT(PED::GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_IN(playerPed, false)), "", "", "", 9);

            // Wait for the user to edit
            while (GAMEPLAY::UPDATE_ONSCREEN_KEYBOARD() == 0) WAIT(0);

            // Make sure they didn't exit without confirming their change, and that they're still in a vehicle
            if (!GAMEPLAY::GET_ONSCREEN_KEYBOARD_RESULT() || !PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed, false)) return;

            // Update the licenseplate
            VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_NUMBER_PLATE_TEXT(PED::GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_IN(playerPed, false), GAMEPLAY::GET_ONSCREEN_KEYBOARD_RESULT());
    }
}
```

Comment: Things go awry around the statement `waitTime = 200;`, essentially due to misplaced braces.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I don't think it has anything to do with misplaced braces, mainly because I can't find any. Instead, the `case` itself is wildly misplaced.

Comment: What are you going to do a year from now when you have to maintain this unreadable code? <g> Write functions; keep the code in each `case` small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to add a case, and you should do so at the correct position. Try adding in case 3 between case 2 and the default case, like so:

```
switch (activeLineIndexVeh)
    {
    case 0:
        if (process_carspawn_menu()) return;
        break;
    case 1:
        if (bPlayerExists)
        {
            if (PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed, 0))
            {
                Vehicle veh = PED::GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_USING(playerPed);
                VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_CUSTOM_PRIMARY_COLOUR(veh, rand() % 255,rand() % 255, rand() % 255);
                    if (VEHICLE::GET_IS_VEHICLE_PRIMARY_COLOUR_CUSTOM(veh))
                        VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_CUSTOM_SECONDARY_COLOUR(veh, rand() % 255, rand() % 255, rand() % 255);
                }
                else
                {
                    set_status_text("player isn't in a vehicle");
                }
            }
            break;
    case 2:
        if (bPlayerExists)
            if (PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed, 0))
                    VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_FIXED(PED::GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_USING(playerPed));
            else
                set_status_text("player isn't in a vehicle");
            break;
            // switchable features
    case 3: 
        Ped playerPed = PLAYER::PLAYER_PED_ID();

        // No point in displaying the keyboard if they aren't in a vehicle
        if (!PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed, false)) return;

        // Invoke keyboard
        GAMEPLAY::DISPLAY_ONSCREEN_KEYBOARD(true, "", "", VEHICLE::GET_VEHICLE_NUMBER_PLATE_TEXT(PED::GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_IN(playerPed, false)), "", "", "", 9);

        // Wait for the user to edit
        while (GAMEPLAY::UPDATE_ONSCREEN_KEYBOARD() == 0) WAIT(0);

        // Make sure they didn't exit without confirming their change, and that they're still in a vehicle
        if (!GAMEPLAY::GET_ONSCREEN_KEYBOARD_RESULT() || !PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed, false)) return;

        // Update the licenseplate
        VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_NUMBER_PLATE_TEXT(PED::GET_VEHICLE_PED_IS_IN(playerPed, false), GAMEPLAY::GET_ONSCREEN_KEYBOARD_RESULT());
        default:
            if (lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState)
                *lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState = !(*lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState);
            if (lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pUpdated)
                *lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pUpdated = true;
        }
    default:
        if (lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState)
            *lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState = !(*lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pState);
        if (lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pUpdated)
            *lines[activeLineIndexVeh].pUpdated = true;
    }
```

Comment: this seems to almost work, but at the 
VEHICLE::SET_VEHICLE_CUSTOM_PRIMARY_COLOUR(veh, rand() % 255,d() % 255, rand() % 255);
line, d is getting the undefined identifier error.

Comment: It seems I made a typo, d should be rand(). I edited my answer

Answer (score 2):

It's what it says. You have a `case` label that's not even on the same street as your `switch`!

Did `case 3:` get lost on its way back from the pub?

Comment: Ok, I added a switch above the case, and it worked. Now there is a new error. At this line playerPed is giving the error: Error: identifier "playerPed" is undefined. Before adding the switch, the playerPed was defined, but afterwards it gave me the error. Sorry if I sound like I don't know much about this kind of thing.

Comment: if (!PED::IS_PED_IN_ANY_VEHICLE(playerPed , false)) return;

Comment: You can't just randomly add a `switch` line in the middle of a program. You have to think about where the code logic should go. We can't tell you where that is: _you_ are the programmer so it is up to _you_ to determine how your program should work!